# Problem with downloading multiple Large files in zip format from Azure Storage in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: azure, .net-core

I am trying to create an API in **.NET 6**, for downloading **multiple(it could be any amount)** large files in zip format from Azure Storage. Here is my code:

```
//Get the document name lists from database
List<MyDocuments> docLists = await GetMyDocumentNameAsync(countryIds);

string accessKey = "*******************************";
string containerName = "TestFolderName";

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        foreach (var doc in docLists)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(doc.FileURL);
            BlobDownloadInfo downloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

            ZipArchiveEntry entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(doc.FileName);
            using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                await downloadInfo.Content.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Reset the stream position to the beginning
    zipStream.Position = 0;
    
    return File(zipStream, "application/zip", "ZipFile.zip");
}
```

But the problem is, when I am sending the request from my Angular application, I am having the CORS policy problem. But I can see there is the CORS policy implemented in my Startup.cs file.

Here is the Cors Policy:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    builder => builder
        .WithOrigins(_appConfiguration["MyCors"].Split(",").Select(o =>o.RemovePostFix("/")).ToArray())
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials())
);
```

Appsettings file:

```
"MyCors": "http://localhost,http://localhost:4200"
```

Here is the problem I am getting:
[image]

[image]

Can anyone give me suggestions how to fix the problem. Also I need a good solution for downloading a very big file from Azure Storage.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the CORS setup code from `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I have just converted my Memory Stream to byte array. Here is the code:

```
//Get the document name lists from database
List<MyDocuments> docLists = await GetMyDocumentNameAsync(countryIds);

string accessKey = "*******************************";
string containerName = "TestFolderName";

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        foreach (var doc in docLists)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(doc.FileURL);
            BlobDownloadInfo downloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

            ZipArchiveEntry entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(doc.FileName);
            using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                await downloadInfo.Content.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    zipStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] byeArray = zipStream.ToArray(); // Here is the solution
    return File(byeArray , "application/zip", "ZipFile.zip");
}
```